# Breaking words in a word cloud (with html, js, css)?

Tags: css, word-cloud, word-break

I cannot make breaking large words (links) in a word cloud app:

https://codepen.io/huqedato/pen/yLEBaaq

```
    .tags {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        max-width: 60%;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        border: rgb(0, 0, 0) solid
    }

    .tag {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0.01rem 0.3rem;
    }

    .tag-link {
        padding: 5px 5px 0;
        transition: 0.3s;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

I've already tried using word-wrap, overflow-wrap on the anchor tag and/or parent
Please help.

Comment: `hyphens: auto;`

Comment: Add 'word-break: break-all;' to your tag class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `word-break: break-all;` to your `.tags`:

```css
.tags {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      max-width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      border: rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
      word-break: break-all;   <--------
}
```

**Image:**
[image: word-break: break-all;]

---

You can either use `hyphens: auto;` as Andrei Fedorov suggested:

```css
.tags {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      max-width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      border: rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
      hyphens: auto;          <--------
}
```

**Image:**
[image: hyphens: auto;]